# Better way of defining filtered endpoints using Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've got a relationship between User's and Image's where every user can have multiple images. I need to define an endpoint that retrieves all images for a specific user:

`GET /users/:id/images`

I've done it like this:

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'images', ImageViewSet)

image_list = ImageViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list'
})

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>[^/]+)/images/$', image_list),
    ...
)
```

**image/views.py**

```
class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = self.kwargs.get('user_id', None)
        if user_id:
            return Image.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
        return super(ImageViewSet, self).get_queryset()
```

It works but I'm not happy with it. Imagine a few additional endpoints that are analogous to `/users/:user_id/images/`, i.e. something along the lines of `/categories/:category_id/images/`, etc. Having `get_queryset` as an entry-point for both of those, letting it distinguish between them based on `kwargs`, doesn't seem very appealing. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You mean a way where you have to define the url at all? How would the app know what to serve where then?

Comment: An idea I had was adding a images action to the UserViewSet, decorating it with @link and just reusing the get action in ImageViewSet. Since asking the question I experimented doing so but it doesn't seem like it's something that is very easy to do.

Comment: Also, having thought more about it, manually defining an url doesn't bother me at all as much as having to dirty down the get_queryset method in this way. Imagine having a few additional endpoints analogous to `/users/:id/images`, something along the lines of `/category/:category_id/images`, etc., having get_queryset as an entry-point for all those seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the basic case you end up specifying a model and a serializer class. There's no reason why you couldn't put both of these in some kind of table and use `kwargs` to do a lookup.

```
LOOK_UP_TABLE = {
    'users' : {
        'model': ...,
        'serializer_class': ...,
    },
    'categories' : {
        ...
    }, 
}
```

If you did this, as well as overriding `get_queryset`, you could override `get_serializer_class` too. You'd then have something pretty generic.

I'm not how much typing you'd really be saving (especially if you use your editor's code snippets features). Or how flexible the resultant system would be. But it's an interesting idea.

Answer (score 2):

You really should use `super()` in `get_queryset()` to get the unfiltered query set and just filter it down based on the `kwargs`.

```
if user_id:
    super(ImageViewSet, self).get_queryset().filter(user_id=user_id)
```

You'll notice that this becomes very generic and can be included into each view as a mixin:

```
class FilterByUserMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = self.kwargs.get('user_id', None)
        queryset = super(FilterByUserMixin, self).get_queryset()
        if user_id:
            queryset = queryset.filter(user_id=user_id)
        return querset


class ImageViewSet(FilterByUserMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer


class CategoryViewSet(FilterbyUserMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```